# which data type should we use for taking input a number which is in between 0<= number <= 10^18

Tags: c++

in this below code , i am getting run time error , i want to input a number which is in between 0<= a <= 10^18 , a is number , also which data type should we use for taking such a big number like 10^18 , help

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int flag=1,cases;
    long int j,i;
    unsigned long long int a;
    cin>>a;
    if(a==0)
    {
        cout<<"yes";
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned long long int temp[a];
        temp[0]=0;
        cases=1;
        i=1;
        while(temp[i]!=a)
        {
            if(cases==1)
            temp[i]=temp[i-1]+1;
            else if(cases==2)
            temp[i]=temp[i-1]+2;
            else if(cases==3)
            temp[i]=temp[i-1]+3;
            cases++;
            if(cases>3)
            cases=1;
            i++;
        }
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(temp[j]==a)
            {
                cout<<"yes";
                break;
            }
            if(j==i-1)
            flag=0;
        }
        if(flag==0)
        cout<<"no";
    }
}
```

Comment: are they going to contain decimals or just integers? someone could clarify range of long long - 19 digits i guess?

Comment: On the various Unix systems (including Linux), uint64_t should be good.

Comment: An unsigned 64bit integer can hold a number up to 2^64 - 1 which is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 which will be enough for you.

Comment: It's dangerous to create variable-length arrays with user input parameters as it can overflow the stack. Use `std::vector` instead. Also don't assume that the type of the *size* of the array, is the same as the type contained in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using temp without initializing it. You do set the first element to zero but then you start iterating from 1. Furter how should temp of any index be to equal a? Unlikely - so your while will not terminate. Sooner or later you will get a run time error.

Try adding

```
temp[a-1] = a;
```

Before the while loop

Or perhaps you actually want the while to be

```
while(i <a)
```

Answer (score -2):

You're already using a unsigned long long int, which is large enough for 18446744073709551615 (2^64 - 1) or greater* 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

My guess is your runtime error is resulting from something other than this.
Be wary of using a variable length array though. Think about how much memory it would take to allocate 10^18 unsigned long long int's for your array? Assuming that it maps to a 64 bit type : 8 bytes per * (10^18) is ~ 7105 PetaBytes.

Comment: If the compiler accepts variable length arrays, and `a` is positive, then `temp[0]` is not unallocated memory. `temp[0]` is *uninitialized*, but that's okay here.

Comment: there's no unallocated memory here.

Answer (score -2):

Let's say you are using unsigned long long int vector.

```
 vector<unsigned long long int> temp ;
```

if you write `cout<<temp.max_size();` it will give you how many elements vector can theoretically manage depending on your machine(((e.g. if you write the same in computer where RAM is bigger, it will give you another number))).It doesn't know how much memory will actually be available when you run the program.Let's say max_size() gives us some number,578910255011, So let's say your a=10^10, unsigned long long = 8 byte,(10^10*8)/1024/1024/1024 = 9.31GB. So your RAM should be equal to 9.31Gb, that's why it's a runtime error, because RAM  is the memory used by running programs. So to solve this problem you should either increase your RAM which for 10^12 unsigned long long elements=931Gb and would cost a fortune :) (if your computer can even support that much) or use something like STXXL

Comment: This doesnt appear to be a valid answer